# Javascript plugin for graph rendering (tree and nodes)

Tags: javascript, graph, tree, rendering, d3.js

I'm looking for a Javascript API to draw this kind of graph :[D3 graph](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/force.html)

Except I don't need/want the "force" effect. Something static is ok, it can be an image generated or some JS rendering (I prefer this).

I've gone through a lot of google results without success, and every JS plugins i've found based on D3 is overkill.

The data will be from 10 to 100 nodes, and performance is not the key (though highly appreciated).

Thank you !

EDIT : a perfect solution would accept XML as data input, but I can accomodate with other formats. Also, I need something as "plug-and-play" as possible, I'm far from mastering JS/webdesign, which is the reason why I don't create my own rendering based on D3.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply delete this part of the example that you have found, and it will become static :

```
  .call(force.drag);
```

Comment: Hi, ok i'm going to try that. I didn't even check if that was possible to manually remove this part, because I thought it was part of the rendering "engine", hence a bit complicated for me. I owe you a beer if that works, thank you.

Comment: I was wrong : just delete the line : ".call(force.drag);" (I edited)

Answer (score 1):

Use This..

http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/ForceDirected/example1.html

Comment: Hi, do you know if it's possible to make the graph "static" (ie: i don't want the drag/drop functionality) ?

Comment: http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/ForceDirected/example1.code.html

Try making zooming:0